# override control template property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, cornerradius

If I have the following XAML defined in generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxCaretBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxTextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,3,0,5" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="5" Padding="2" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource TextBoxBackgroundColor}" />
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource TextBoxBorderColor}" />
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlLightColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorderSelectedBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="5" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And in my view I have defined the following XAML to display a TextBox using the above style.

```
<TextBox Name="UserName" attachedProperties:KeyboardNavigationExt.TabOnEnter="True" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" cal:Message.Attach="[Event TextChanged] = [Action CanLogin]" />
```

This display a TextBox on the view with a `CornerRadius` of 5 on the `Border` in the `Template`.

Now for my question, I have a scenario where there are two TextBox adjacent to each other and I would like to specify the `CornerRadius` for both TextBox something like the below.

```
<TextBox Name="UserName" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" attachedProperties:KeyboardNavigationExt.TabOnEnter="True" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" cal:Message.Attach="[Event TextChanged] = [Action CanLogin]" />
```

But TextBox does not have a `CornerRadius` how can I achieve this so that I am able to change the `CornerRadius` of the `Border` in the view XAML

Comment: Create another attached property (proxy), as you did with `KeyboardNavigationExt.TabOnEnter`, but this one of type `CornerRadius`, set default value in the `Style` and in template bind `ConrnerRadius` to that attached property of `TemplatedParent`. Like that you will be able to change the value per `TextBox`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774408/change-style-during-runtime/31774718#31774718) answer

Comment: How would i bind that in the template? i have tried `CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"` but i get an error

Comment: Check the link to the answer in previous comment. You use `RelativeSource` to `TemplatedParent` binding

Comment: Thanks, that's the bit I was missing, I completely missed the link in your comment above, if you add your answer then I can mark as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you need proxy property that you can set against `TextBox` and bind in template. So create `AttachedProprty` of `CornerRadius` type

```
public static class AttachedProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(AttachedProperties), new UIPropertyMetadata());

    public static void SetCornerRadius(DependencyObject d, CornerRadius source)
    {
        d.SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, source);
    }

    public static CornerRadius GetCornerRadius(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (CornerRadius)d.GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
    }
}
```

change `ControlTemplate` and bind to that property of `TemplatedParent`

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border CornerRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:AttachedProperties.CornerRadius)}"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

add`Setter` to your `Style` with default value

```
<Setter Property="local:AttachedProperties.CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
```

and then you can change it manually against each `TextBox`

```
<TextBox local:AttachedProperties.CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" .../>
```